# Martingale and Lenglart inequality

Tags: inequality, martingales

Suppose that $M$ is a square-integrable Martingale with $M_0=0$. I want to apply the Lenglart inequality to $M$ concluding that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\sup_{s\leq t}\left|M_s\right|\geq \varepsilon\right]\leq \frac{\eta}{\varepsilon}+\mathbb{P}\left[\left<M\right>_t\geq\eta\right]
$$
In order to do so I need to prove that $M$ is $L$-dominated by $\left<M\right>$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[\left|M_{\tau}\right|]\leq\mathbb{E}[\left<M\right>_{\tau}]$ for every bounded stopping time $\tau$. What I can prove is the following
$$
\mathbb{E}[\left|M_t\right|]\leq \left(\mathbb{E}[M_t^2]\right)^{1/2} =\left(\mathbb{E}[M^{\prime}_t+\left<M\right>_t]\right)^{1/2}=\left(\mathbb{E}[\left<M\right>_t]\right)^{1/2},\quad(1)
$$
where I have used the Jensen's inequality and the Doob-Meyer decomposition $M^2_t=M^{\prime}_t+\left<M\right>_t$, with $M^{\prime}_t$ martingale with $M^{\prime}_0=0$ and so $\mathbb{E}[M^{\prime}_t]=0$. Nevertheless I am not sure that $(1)$ is enough to use the Lenglart inequality.

Comment: Pls use that $M^2$ is L-dominated by ⟨M,M⟩.

Comment: @JGWang I could use the fact that $M^2$ is $L$-dominated by $\left<M\right>_t$ and then the inequality $\sup_{s\leq t}M_t^2\leq(\sup_{s\leq t}M_t)^2$ but this does seem to help. In fact I get $\mathbb{P}[\sup_{s\leq t}M_t^2\geq\varepsilon]\leq\mathbb{P}[(\sup_{s\leq t}M_t)^2\geq\varepsilon]$, which is not going in the right direction.

Comment: The inequality $\mathsf{P}[\sup\limits_{s\le t}|M_s|\ge \epsilon ]\le \frac{\eta}{\epsilon}+\mathsf{P}[\langle M \rangle_t \ge \eta] $ couldn't be true,
except  $ M=0 $.

Comment: @JGWang Thanks, I think I figured it out. It must be $\mathsf{P}[\sup\limits_{s\le t}|M_s|\ge \epsilon ]\le \frac{\eta}{\epsilon^2}+\mathsf{P}[\langle M \rangle_t \ge \eta]$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this form is correct.